# JSON memory leaks iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, json, memory-leaks

iPhone app is getting slow while testing in the performance tool,but it works fine while simply build and run on the device.I am getting following leaks:

1. `[NSCFString CopyWithZone];`
2. `[NSCFStringAppendString];`
3. JSON Parser : `[SBJSONParser ScanRestOfDictionary];`

Basically.what i get is the leaks are coming while using JSON Parser because data is load from server in the JSON format.2

Comment: So what do you want from us? Check in instruments what piece of code gives you a leak and try to fix it. If you can't - post that code here so we will be able to help you. Without actual code we can just sympathize with you

Comment: These leaks are not in code.. These leaks are showing in framework.....